# Use Object.assign or Spread Operator in React/Redux? Which is a better practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some confusion about using `Object.assign` for React and Redux.

I read this [article](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html).

It says ES6 is not supported by all browsers but I have started using it.

I have two questions:

1. Is it the right decision to continue with `Object.assign`?
2. What is the alternative?

My Code

```
export const selectDiameter = (scaleData, size) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_DIAMETER,
    payload: Object.assign({}, scaleData, {
         diameter: Object.assign({}, scaleData.diameter, {
             selected_tube_diameter: size,
             is_clicked: true,
             audio: Object.assign({}, scaleData.diameter.audio, {
               is_played: true
             })
         })
      })
   }
}
```

What is the alternative for the above code?

Comment: redux guides specifically mention using [object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) instead of `Object.assign` http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html

Comment: rest-spread is the alternative (and looks nicer). Either way if you're using ES6 you'll want to transpile to ES5 for now anyway.

Comment: Unrelated, but please use some whitespace in your code so it's legible. Also unrelated, but JS convention uses camelCase, e.g., `selectedTubeDiameter` instead of snake-case `selected_tube_diameter`. It doesn't make any sense to use `Object.assign` when you're just dumping stuff into an empty object you control anyway.

Comment: Hi Dave Thanks for advice I need to know all  good practices for Modern Javascript Could you please send me some link ... So i could get ideas like you said above

Comment: @VickySmart The AirBnB JS and React style guides are a good place to start, but there are tons of searchable resources.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Redux docs recommends you to use the spread operator approach instead of the `Object.assign`

As per the docs:

> An alternative approach is to use the object spread syntax proposed
>   for the next versions of JavaScript which lets you use the spread
>   (...) operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to
>   another in a more succinct way. The object spread operator is
>   conceptually similar to the ES6 array spread operator

The advantage of using the object spread syntax becomes more apparent when you're composing complex objects

Using the Spread operator syntax

```
export const selectDiameter = (scaleData,size) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_DIAMETER,
    payload: {...scaleData, 
                 diameter: {
                          ...scaleData.diameter,
                           selectedTube: size,
                           isClicked: true,
                           audio: {
                                ...scaleData.diameter.audio,
                                isPlayed: true
                           }
                 }

             }
   }
}
```

It still uses ES6. See the **[Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html)** for more info on configuring your code for the same

However when you are dealing with the nested data. I prefer to use `immutability-helpers`

For your code it will be like

```
import update from 'immutability-helpers';

export const selectDiameter = (scaleData,size) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_DIAMETER,
    payload: update(scaleData, {
         diameter: {
            selectedTube: { $set: size},
            isClicked: { $set: true},
            audio: {
                isPlayed: {$set: true}
            }
         }
    })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to the code you posted is using object spreading:

```
export const selectDiameter = (scaleData, size) => ({
    type: SELECT_DIAMETER,
    payload: {
        ...scaleData,
        diameter: {
            ...scaleData.diameter,
            selected_tube_diameter: size,
            is_clicked: true,
            audio: {
                ...scaleData.diameter.audio,
                is_played:true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have also shortened the body of the arrow function in your code to simply returning the object.

You can use the object rest spread syntax by using the Babel plugin [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Install it like this:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

Configure its use in your *.babelrc* like this:

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok may be I was not really right but this is from Dan Abramov (redux creator)

> Finally, you need to remember that Object.assign is a new method in
>   ES6, so it is not natively available in all the browsers. You should
>   use a polyfill, either the one that ships with Babel or a standalone
>   Object.assign polyfill, to use it without risking crashing your
>   website.
>
> Another option that doesn't require a polyfill is to use the new
>   object spread operator, which is not part of ES6. However, it is
>   proposed for ES7. It is fairly popular, and it is enabled in Babel if
>   you use the stage two preset.

Answer (score 0):

Object spread is ES7 syntax, render supported by Babel, Object.assign() is ES6 syntax, it not support in some browser. 
That's why you should use Object spread instead of Object.assign()