# Replace array inside object - Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an array of elements which was updated inside an action, now I want to update it in the store. Currently I have something like:

```
navigation
|_navigationItems:[{1:"foo"}, {2:"bar"}, {3:"foobar"}]
```

The thing is I was doing the following:

```
case types.UPDATE_NAVIGATION:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    navigationItems: action.payload.items,
  });
```

where items is: `[{1:"zoo"}, {2:"foobar"}]`

but store was not updated succesfully.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Is your action getting triggered. Can you console.log() within this case statement and see if you are getting the result

Comment: I put a `console.log()` just after the `case` is called and there I have the array updated.

Comment: Try the spread operator syntax: `case types.UPDATE_NAVIGATION:
  return {...state, navigationItems: action.payload.items}`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please, post it as an answer, it worked. But now: why did it work? Is still possible to do it with `Object.assign`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React docs suggest on using the spread operator syntax over `Object.assign`

Use:

```
case types.UPDATE_NAVIGATION: 
     return {
         ...state, navigationItems: action.payload.items
     }
```

Comment: Object.assign should have worked for you, you were doing it correctly as far as I can see.

Comment: You can refer this answer of mine as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/using-object-assign-in-react-redux-is-a-good-practice , provides more information.