# update property value of array of object using es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT_LIKES':
            const i = action.index 
            return [
                ...state.slice(0,i),
                {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1},
                ...state.slice(i + 1),
            ]
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default posts
```

Above code worked but for me it's not so elegant, it look super confusing and not so flexible. What if my id is in number, I can't do `slice(i + 1)`, anymore. I can use map with object assign to solve it but I'm looking for more alternative to do `update property value of array of object using es6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative would be to make use of `update` from npm package [immutability-helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) which is every easy to handle and understand even in case of deep nested states and

```
import update from `immutability-helper`


function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'INCREMENT_LIKES':
            const i = action.index 
            return update(state, {
                 [i]: {
                      likes: {
                            $set: state[i].likes + 1
                      }
                 }
            })

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default posts
```

Comment: woala this is great alternative. what if I don't use redux, is immutabity still matters?

Comment: You can still use it, even with normal ReactJS immutability matters

Comment: I like to use object.assign like this http://jsfiddle.net/qafdt6so/ what is your thought?

Comment: Object.assign is not recommended according to the redux docs, you should go with spread operator instead. However I find immutability helper very helpful

Comment: for what reason it's not recommended? if you use webpack you surely have used babel. I don't see any problem not using es2015/es6 stuff

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/using-object-assign-in-react-redux-is-a-good-practice