# Does Object destructing work by reference or it clones the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutability

I need to copy an object from `this.state` to change some of its property values.

For example in the following method state is being mutated directly (`this.state.errors = {}`)

```
   authorFormIsValid = () => {
    var formIsValid = true;
    this.state.errors = {}; //clear any previous errors.

    if (this.state.author.firstName.length < 3) {
      this.state.errors.firstName = 'First name must be at least 3 characters.';
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    if (this.state.author.lastName.length < 3) {
      this.state.errors.lastName = 'Last name must be at least 3 characters.';
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    this.setState({errors: this.state.errors});
    return formIsValid;
  };
```

To avoid this, I know that we can use :

a) The [object spread operator](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html)

```
let errors={...this.state.errors};
```

b) Or [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let errors=Object.assign({},this.state.errors);
```

But sometimes I've seem some examples in which `object destructuring` it is used like this:

```
authorFormIsValid = () => {
    let formIsValid = true;

   //Destructuring error and authors from this.state
    let {errors, author} = this.state;

    errors = {}; //clear any previous errors.

    if (author.firstName.length < 3) {
      errors.firstName = 'First name must be at least 3 characters.';
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    if (author.lastName.length < 3) {
      errors.lastName = 'Last name must be at least 3 characters.';
      formIsValid = false;
    }

    this.setState({errors});
    return formIsValid;
  };
```

So my question is , is it `object destructuring` equivalent to the other two methods mentioned above? I mean, will I avoid mutating the state directly by using simple `object destructuring` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Object destructuring` works by `reference` and hence you should not be mutating the object after destructuring it. So the practice of

```
let {errors, author} = this.state;

errors = {}; //clear any previous errors.
```

is actually wrong.

See a snippet of reference call below

```js
let obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 1
  }
}

let { foo } = obj;

console.log(foo.bar);      // 1
console.log(obj.foo.bar); // 1

foo.bar++;

console.log(foo.bar);      // 2
console.log(obj.foo.bar); // 2
```

Comment: So I guess I'll have to stick to using either the object spread operator or Object.assign, right?

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you to go with Spread operator considering that redux docs also recommend it. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/using-object-assign-in-react-redux-is-a-good-practice/43376980#43376980

Answer (score 2):

No. Object destructuring just assign the same object inside the 'this.state' to a different variable.

```
let {errors, author} = this.state;
```

So the new `error` variable refer to the same error object inside the `this.state`

However, next line `errors = {};` doesn't mutate the `this.state`. It only rereference the `error` variable to a new empty object. So the given code still doesn't  do a state mutation. In fact, there is no any meaning of having `error` in this object destructuring. It's similar to something like this.

```
let errors = this.state.errors;
errors = {};
```

Which is essentially no difference from this.

```
let errors = {};
```

Comment: Yes in that line there's still not a mutation, but what about the following lines : `this.state.errors.firstName = 'First name must be at least 3 characters.';` ?

Comment: That's a state mutation. And the previous line also, `this.state.errors = {}`

Comment: Wait! Are you trying to tell that there's nothing wrong with directly assigning state to a variable, modify that variable and then using  that variable in `this.setState()` ?

Comment: No that's wrong. But `error = {}` isn't a modifying variable. It's a reassignment. Modifying variable is something like this. `errors.firstName = 'First name...`. There is a difference.