# React Redux reducer is overwriting values LOAD_SUCCESS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have a profilesReducer that I want to use to store 1 or more user profiles in my redux store. As an example think Twitter, which needs to store my profile as well as other profiles.

Here is my profilesReducer.js:

```
 import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function profilesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return [Object.assign({}, action.profile)]
    case types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state.filter(profile => profile.id !== action.profile.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.profile)
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The problem is LOAD is receiving more than one profile (distinguished by profile.id) but is overwriting the existing profile in the store instead of appending/updating.

I need LOAD_PROFILE to allow for more than 1 user's profile in the store. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure your code needs to change to this.

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function profilesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return [...Object.assign({}, action.profile)]
    case types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return [
        ...state.filter(profile => profile.id !== action.profile.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.profile)
      ]
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The way you had it, you were simply returning an array containing this one item in `action.profile`, but you need to add your item in to the array that already has the other items. You also cannot simply push as that would mutate the array. This line is all you need to change.

`return [Object.assign({}, action.profile)]`
Does not append

`return [...Object.assign({}, action.profile)]`
does append and does not mutate.

Answer (score 2):

Spread existing state and just add new profile at the end:

```
case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
  return [...state, action.profile]
```

`Object.assing({}, action.profile)` is unnecessary, since all that it does here is copying `action.profile` into a new empty object `{}` and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I have changed my solution, it includes a way to update an array.

Here is a [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/zk9r6k1z4p) to test: https://codesandbox.io/s/zk9r6k1z4p

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = []

export default function profilesReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, action.profile]
    case types.UPDATE_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return state.map( (profile) => {
        if(profile.id !== action.profile.id) {
          return profile;
        }

        return {
          ...profile,
          ...action.profile
        };    
     });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: why use spread an Object.assign together when only one can do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with either using `Object.assign` or the `spread operator` syntax, You need not use both

With **[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**,

```
case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
  return Object.assign([], state, action.profile)
```

With **[Spread operator syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**

```
case types.LOAD_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
  return [...state, action.profile]
```

However React docs advise you to use Spread syntax over Object.assign, See this post:

[Using Object.assign in React/Redux is a Good Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/using-object-assign-in-react-redux-is-a-good-practice/43376980#43376980)