# Remove first element from array in reducer state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to keep maximum array count to 10. When new object is added to reducer state, if the array count exceeds 10 I want to remove first object. How can I do this ?

This is my code:

```
switch(action.type) {
    case types.RECENTLY_VIEWED_ITEM:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: [
            ...(state.data.filter(item => (item.id !== action.payload.id))), 
            action.payload
            ]
        });

    case types.REMOVE_RECENTLY_VIEWED_ITEM:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: [
            ...(state.data.splice(0, 1))
        ]});

        default:
        return state;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and not [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice),

`splice` returns you the array of deleted elements while `slice` returns you the array after deletion of the element

```
case types.REMOVE_RECENTLY_VIEWED_ITEM:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
    data: [
        ...state.data.slice(1, 10)
    ]});

    default:
    return state;
```

Instead of mixing `Object.assign` and `Spread operator` you can just use Spread operator.

```
case types.REMOVE_RECENTLY_VIEWED_ITEM:
    return { ...state, 
         data: [
            ...state.data.slice(1, 10)
         ]
    };

    default:
    return state;
```

See this answer as well

[Using Object.assign in React/Redux is a Good Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/using-object-assign-in-react-redux-is-a-good-practice/43376980#43376980)

Comment: state.data.slice(1) will not keep maximum array count 10. it will just copy all the data except the first. So if array length is 15, it will return array with last 14 data.

Comment: @Ved OP is not checking the count anywhere, I guess he is just calling the action when length is more than 10, Thats what I could infer

Comment: What I see in question : "I want to keep maximum array count to 10. if the array count exceeds 10 I want to remove first object".

Answer (score 0):

Change splice with slice and You can do like this:

```js
 case types.REMOVE_RECENTLY_VIEWED_ITEM:
return Object.assign({}, state, {
 data: [
            ...(state.data.slice(state.data.length-10, (state.data.length))
     ]});
    default:
    return state;
```