# What is the best practice to return a new state from reducers in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the best practice to return a new state from reducers - is it by using `$set` and `update` from `immutability-helpers`, or by using `Object.assign()`?

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/use-object-assign-or-spread-operator-in-react-redux-which-is-a-better-practise/43376980#43376980. Also its upto you, All you need to do is to update state in an immutable manner

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't use immutability helpers when working on a project where it's easy to manage the state. If you have a really large state it can be helpful to use immutability helpers so you won't be that likely to make mistakes.

And for returning the state in a reducer, it's a common practice to return the new state by using the spread operator. This would look something like this:

`return {...state, newProp: 'value', etc...}`

Answer (score 0):

you can create new state in reducer in redux and also change the state by using set method and you can return into your index page as props

ex:in reducer you write as follows

return state.set('tasks', action.response)

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should need a clear understanding of redux. it's a back store on your frontend. redux store data as a stacking technique FIFO or LIFO as you defined. 
You don't make it reassign, just return with action-object using ES6 `SPREAD` operator and using destructuring. I try to give an example below:

```
const postsReducerDefaultState = [];
const postsReducer = (state=postsReducerDefaultState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
  case 'ADD_POST':
    return [action.post, ...state];
  case 'REMOVE_POST':
    return state.filter(post => post.id !== action.id)
  case 'SET_POSTS':
    return action.posts;
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
export default postsReducer;
```

`ADD_POST`: return `[action.post, ...state]` latest first then spreading your old post.
`SET_POSTS`: return `action.posts` that you have passed with your action.
 If you want to set an object property then use destructuring

```
return {
      ...state,
      text:action.text
    }
```

`text` property already have in your state. if haven't then it will add a property to your state. I think it helps you to understand something redux.

Comment: it depends on `action.type`. if it does not match any `case` then return default state which is `postsReducerDefaultState`