# React warning: functions are not valid as a React child when i use Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using react for front-end and node for back-end, what i'm trying to do is fetch data from server to update the user entries on the front-end. there is a solution that i can use Object.assign() to re-render user entries but the problem is I get

**Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.**

when i added Object.assing() to code it results in warning but before that i had no issues. What could be the solution here to re-render without warrning?

here is the code regarding my problem

```
class App extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        input: '',
        imgUrl: '',
        box: { },
        route: 'signin',
        isSignedIn: false,
        user: {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            email: '',
            entries: 0,
            joined: ''
        }
    }
}

onButtonSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({imgUrl: this.state.input});

    fetch('http://localhost:3001/image', {
        method: 'put',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: this.state.user.id
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json)
    .then(count => {
        this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count}))
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
        <Navigation isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
        { this.state.route === 'home'?  
            <div>
                <Rank name={this.state.user.name} entries={this.state.user.entries} />
                <ImageLinkForm onInputChange = {this.onInputChange} onButtonSubmit = {this.onButtonSubmit}/>
                <FaceRecognition box = {this.state.box} imgUrl = {this.state.imgUrl} />
            </div>
        :  ( this.state.route === 'signin'? 
                <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            :   <Register loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}/>
            )           
       }
  </div>
);
```

Here is component where entries gets printed

```
 import React from 'react';

 const Rank = ({ name, entries}) => {
     return (
        <div>
            <div className='rank'>
                {`${name} your current rank is...`}
            </div>
            <div className='white f1 '>
                {entries}
            </div>
       </div>
   );
}

export default Rank;
```

Here is server Side code where entries gets updated

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body;
    let found = false;
    database.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.id === id){
            found = true;
            user.entries++;
            return res.json(user.entries);
        }
    });

    if (!found) {
        res.status(400).json('not found');
    }
});
```

Why do i get this warning only when i added Object.assign()? its been 2 days and i cant figure it out

Comment: Useful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376849/use-object-assign-or-spread-operator-in-react-redux-which-is-a-better-practise).

Answer (score 0):

In React you should never manually update the state of something programmatically outside of a **setState** call, which is what you're doing when you use **Object.assign** in your example.

https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead:

```
.then(count => {
    this.setState({...this.state.user, entries: count})
})
```

Comment: thank you, it works but i no longer get warning but entries doesn't seem to re-render when it gets updated.